# Is "I don't care about learning the stuff but rather if they would hire me" grammatically accurate?

Tags: grammar

I haven't found any example with this word combination.
I wonder whether "about" would be a much more suitable option as to say "but rather about being hired"

Answer (score 2):

While it sounds awkward, and I would add a comma, I believe it's correct to say:

> I don't care about learning the stuff, but rather if they would hire me.

However, it would sound better if you made the two parts of the sentence agree.  If you don't care about "learning the stuff", you do care about "getting hired".

> I don't care about learning the stuff, but about getting hired.

Or you can express it as two sentences:

> I don't care about learning the stuff. I care about getting hired.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means:

> I don't care about learning the stuff, but rather I care about if they would hire me.

Using "about being hired" is also good

Comment: Yes. My choice would be "I am not interested in learning the stuff, but rather about their hiring me". But everyone to their own way of expression.

Comment: Is it they hiring me or their hiring me or they are hiring me?

Comment: @Quique "their" or "them"

Comment: @Quique Should be "...their hiring me" - in my view. There are other ways of saying the same thing, but the way it is phrased in the question is not idiomatic.

Comment: @WS2 [ "them" + gerund ] isn't correct prescriptively, but descriptively it certainly can be